# create user with node js (findOne is not a function)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Iam trying to create user using sequelize and postgres db. Iam trying to post to '/api/signup' but it keeps giving me an error saying thata findOne is not a function.

This is how my AuthController.js looks like

```
   exports.signup = async(req,res) =>{
  
  
    const {nom,prenom, poste, telephone, email, password} = req.body;
    

    //Verifie si toute les donnee ont ete entree
    if(!prenom || !poste ||!telephone ||!email ||!password){
      return res.status(409).send("you may need to enter all the field");
    }

    //Verifie si l'utilisateur exist deja en comparant son phonenumber et le email dans ls base de donne

    User.findOne({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [{telephone: telephone}, {email:email}]
      }
    })
      .then(user =>{
          if((!user)){
              return res.status(409).json({message: "User already exist"})
          }

          //Hashage du mot de passe entre

          bcrypt.hash(password, parseInt(10))
            .then(hash =>{
              req.body.password = hash;

                User.create(req.body)
                .then(user => res.json({message: "User succesfully created", data:user}))
                .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: "Data error", error:err}));


            })
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: "Hash process error", error:err}));


      })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: "Data error", error:err}));



     
}
```

This is my Authroute.js

```
const AuthController = require('../controller1/AuthController')
const {login} = AuthController;
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
      );
      next();
    });

    app.post("/signup",AuthController.signup);

    app.post("/signin", AuthController.signin);

    return app 
}
```

This is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const router = require("./Route/index").routes

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "*"
};



app.use(cors(corsOptions));
//parse request of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(cookieParser());
//parse request of content-type - apllication/x-ww-form-urllencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));



app.use('/api', router)
//simple route
```

After running my project i have tested on postman to see if everything is working but i had this error in my console

```
C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\controller1\AuthController.js:33
    User.findOne({
         ^

TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
    at exports.signup (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\controller1\AuthController.js:33:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\Route\AuthRoute.js:12:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dzeufack\Desktop\flysoft_maisonier\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Where do you define `User`?

Comment: Well what is `User`?

Comment: The user is the variable which i used to import the table User in  my models